# Leak memory with ffmpeg in c++

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, avcodec

Im using ffmpeg libs to decode sa video, and i noticed that there os a leak memory, avcodec_send_packet allocate some time more memory without free it with av_packet_unref()
do u have any explication ?

Comment: Which ffmpeg version are you using ? Which OS ? I am using 4.2.1 on Windows and have not encountered this problem.

Comment: 5.8 /ubuntu on c++

Comment: The latest stable version at the moment seems to be 5.0. In any case you can try to use a bit older version.